# Select value from custom key/value variable in Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I want dome devices connected to a Grafana dashboard. Each device has a name. I wanted to "attatch" an IP to each device, but I can't modify the database, so I figured I could use custom variables.

The name of the device is saved on the "name" variable and I used a key/value custom variable called "list" with the name of the device as the key, and the IP as the value, like this:

```
DEVICE 1 : 192.168.0.26, DEVICE 2 : 192.168.0.27
```

Now I want to display the correct IP when the user select the name of the device but I haven't figured out the right way to do it.

I've tried the following:

- Use the "Repeat by variable option" in the panel where I want to display the IP in, and select the variable "name".
- Tried to access the value using this sintax: `${list[name]}` and `${list.${name}}`
- Using this sintax `${list.name}` seems to work, but it only displays the first value.

I can't make it happened. Please help me with the right sintax or the right way to do this.

Comment: It is not clear how you have defined that variable and what kind of syntax is expected after variable interpolation.

Answer (score 5):

Correct syntax for custom variables is `${variable:text}` and `${variable:value}`. So in your case `${variable:value}` will print IP.